# open InAppBrowser on ionicModal

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I want open a web page in my app, I know I should use ngCordova `InAppBrowser` plugin, but how can I open the webpage in `$ionicModal` ? like twitter, facebook mobile apps and ...

I have this button :

```
<button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="doPay()">Pay</button>
```

and in `doPay()` I have :

```
$scope.doPay = function(){
    window.open(url, '_system', 'location=no');
};
```

but this code use external app (`Safari`), I want open in my application.

Comment: Please review this answer :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34150840/inappbrowser-passing-a-callback-function/35601054#35601054

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open the web inside your app you have to use the `_blank` option instead of `_system`

```
$scope.doPay = function(){
    window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no');
};
```

Edit: window.open no longer works as default, to re enable it you’ll need to add this code

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
}
```

Or use cordova.InAppBrowser.open instead of window.open

Comment: Thanks, but this will open default modal, I want use Ionic Modal, is it possible?

Comment: no, it's not possible, the plugin opens a native window, ionic modal opens an html view

Comment: This does not work anymore. Just tried it

Comment: Using ionic in-app-browser, you can do this: `const browser = this.iab.create(this.url,'_blank');`

Comment: trying to do the same, I want to open the web view inside an ionic modal.